# DateDiff Calculate Age Incorrectly

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access I am using the DateDiff formula in a text box on a form to calculate a person's age. The user types the date of birth and another text box called “Age” calculates and displays the age based on that date of birth and today’s date. But for some reason the age is incorrect. Here is the formula I am using to determining age.

```
=DateDiff("yyyy",[txtDoB1],Date())    'today is 2/12/2021
=DateDiff("yyyy", #5/24/1979#, #2/12/2021#)     'this has the dates manually typed in
```

The DateDiff formula returns 42 as the age. That is not correct. It should be 41. Why is the DateDiff formula resulting in an incorrect age? What am I doing wrong?

[image: screen shot of Access form with problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateDiff formula does not calculate the difference between years very well. If you use `"yyyy"` in the DateDiff formula then it only uses the year portion of the 2 dates provided in the formula to calculate the difference in years. This leads to undesirable results. In your example the DateDiff formula would take `2021` from 2/12/2021 and subtract it by `1979` from 5/24/1979. Or in other words, `2021 - 1979 = 42`.

Instead try using the below formula.

```
=Int((Date()-[txtDoB1])/365.25)      '365.25 compensates for leap years
=Int((#2/11/2021#-#5/24/1979#)/365.25)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution using DateDiff is from Microsoft. I have used it and it works well. The link is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Date-Time/calculate-age

```
Function Age(varBirthDate As Variant) As Integer
Dim varAge As Variant
 
If IsNull(varBirthDate) Then Age = 0: Exit Function
 
varAge = DateDiff("yyyy", varBirthDate, Now)
If Date < DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(varBirthDate), _
Day(varBirthDate)) Then
varAge = varAge - 1
End If
Age = CInt(varAge)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff returns the difference in calendar years.

For calculating age correct for any dates, *DateAdd* must be used:

```vb
' Returns the difference in full years from DateOfBirth to current date,
' optionally to another date.
' Returns zero if AnotherDate is earlier than DateOfBirth.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   any date/time value of data type Date
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28th when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29th
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2015-11-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Age( _
    ByVal DateOfBirth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal AnotherDate As Variant) _
    As Integer
    
    Dim ThisDate    As Date
    Dim Years       As Integer
      
    If IsDate(AnotherDate) Then
        ThisDate = CDate(AnotherDate)
    Else
        ThisDate = Date
    End If
    
    ' Find difference in calendar years.
    Years = DateDiff("yyyy", DateOfBirth, ThisDate)
    If Years > 0 Then
        ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
        ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of DateOfBirth.
        If DateDiff("d", ThisDate, DateAdd("yyyy", Years, DateOfBirth)) > 0 Then
            Years = Years - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Years < 0 Then
        Years = 0
    End If
    
    Age = Years
  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to convert months to years:

```vb
Public Function DateDiffYears(date1 As Variant, date2 As Variant) As Integer
    If IsNull(date1) Then DateDiffYears = 0: Exit Function
    If IsNull(date2) Then DateDiffYears = 0: Exit Function
    DateDiffYears = Int(DateDiff("m", date1, date2) / 12)
End Function
```